# Android : accelerometer indicates gravity more than 10 instead of 9.8

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors, gravity

I wrote a program to find gravity from accelerometer. I put the phone(galaxy S4) on the ground. but z axis's value is 10.5 instead of 9.8...
I don't want to use gravity sensor or sth else... I just want to test accelerometer.
my code is:

```
  @Override
  public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER)
    {
        onAccelerationSensorChanged(event.values, event.timestamp);
        Log.d("acceleration","is :"+event.values[2]);
    }
  }
```

event.values[0] and 1 are correct(When I put the phone on the edge I recieve 9.8 and -9.8 correctly). but problem is in event.values[2]. when I lay the phone on the table I give numbers around 10.5(screen on the top) and -9(svreen on the bottom). what is the problem? how can I fix it?

Comment: Add your program to find gravity from accelerometer. So that people can help you.

Comment: @BalajiG I just check event.values of accelerometer... I didn't do any thing else.

Comment: Anyways , if you share the code which you tried and then asked doubt it would be clear.

Comment: @BalajiG I added the simple code...

Comment: Try calibrating the motion sensor and check.

Comment: @jion: did you resolve this error? if yes can you plz share your code? thanks